# Saving and redirecting with a model and revision model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, associations

I'm relatively new to RoR, and have been working on a lesson-site sharing back-end.

Currently I have two models: Lesson and Revision. The idea is that a teacher would create a lesson (with a title, description, etc.), at the lesson/new page. The form would redirect to another form with other fields (content, comments) at the lesson/lesson_id/revision/new page. Eventually teachers will be able to "save and modify" lessons by copying revisions to their own profile, but the model isn't there yet.

I'm still focusing on two supposedly basic issues, both in creating new lessons and revisions.

1) Saving the lessons to a user, and revisions to a user and lesson. At one point I had revisions saved to users, but lessons were not saving.

2) Redirecting from the lesson form to the revision form, and the revision form to the revision page. I've tried changing the redirects in the controller and one of the form_for blocks, to no avail. The new lesson form still wants to go to /lessons rather than /lesson/1/revision/new, which I've tried to redirect to with new_lesson_revision_path. The revision form also just goes back to /revisions, which will be an admin index but I'd rather go to /lesson/1/revision/1 etc.

Thanks in advance for any advice on either or both of these issues!

Below is my code for reference. An excerpt from routes.rb:

```
resources :lessons
resources :revisions #For index pages for admin
resources :lessons do
  resources :revisions
end
```

Models

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :stable, :summary, :title, :time_created
  has_many :revisions, :class_name => "Revision"
  has_many :users, :through => :revisions
end

class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :lesson_id, :user_id, :description, :content, :time_updated
  belongs_to :lesson, :class_name => "Lesson", :foreign_key => "lesson_id"
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lesson
end
```

Lessons
new.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <h2>New lesson</h2>
  <%= form_for @lesson do |f| %>
  <%= render "form" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', lessons_path %>
<% else %>
<h3> Please <%= link_to 'sign in', new_user_session_path %> or <%= link_to 'create an account', new_user_registration_path %> to make and save lessons.</h3>
<% end %>
```

Lessons
_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @lesson, :url => new_lesson_revision_path(@lesson_id, @revision) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :summary %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :summary %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stable %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :stable %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Revisions
new.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <h2>New revision</h2>
  <%= form_for @revision do |f| %>
    <%= render "form" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', lessons_path %>
<% else %>
  <h3> Please <%= link_to 'sign in', new_user_session_path %> or <%= link_to 'create an account', new_user_registration_path %> to make and save revisions.</h3>
<% end %>
```

Revisions
_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@revision) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Lesson Controller: new/create

```
  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @lesson = Lesson.new(params[:lesson])
    #@user.lessons << @lesson
    params[:lesson][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params[:lesson][:lesson_id] = @lesson.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_lesson_revision_path(params[:lesson_id]), notice: 'Your lesson was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @lesson, status: :created, location: new_lesson_revision_path}
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Revisions Controller: new/create

```
  def new
    @revision = Revision.new
  end
  def create
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
    @revision = @lesson.revisions.new(params[:revision])
    @revision.user_id = current_user.id
    @revision.lesson_id = @lesson.id
    @revision.time_updated = DateTime.now
    respond_to do |format|
      if @revision.save
       format.html { redirect_to current_user.profile }
       format.json { }
      else
      render :new
      end
    end
  end
```

Lastly here are most of the results from my rake routes:

```
          home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                            home#index
             profile POST   /profile(.:format)                               profiles#create
         new_profile GET    /profile/new(.:format)                           profiles#new
        edit_profile GET    /profile/edit(.:format)                          profiles#edit
                     GET    /profile(.:format)                               profiles#show
                     PUT    /profile(.:format)                               profiles#update
                     DELETE /profile(.:format)                               profiles#destroy
             lessons GET    /lessons(.:format)                               lessons#index
                     POST   /lessons(.:format)                               lessons#create
          new_lesson GET    /lessons/new(.:format)                           lessons#new
         edit_lesson GET    /lessons/:id/edit(.:format)                      lessons#edit
              lesson GET    /lessons/:id(.:format)                           lessons#show
                     PUT    /lessons/:id(.:format)                           lessons#update
                     DELETE /lessons/:id(.:format)                           lessons#destroy
    lesson_revisions GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/revisions(.:format)          revisions#index
                     POST   /lessons/:lesson_id/revisions(.:format)          revisions#create
 new_lesson_revision GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/revisions/new(.:format)      revisions#new
edit_lesson_revision GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/revisions/:id/edit(.:format) revisions#edit
     lesson_revision GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/revisions/:id(.:format)      revisions#show
                     PUT    /lessons/:lesson_id/revisions/:id(.:format)      revisions#update
                     DELETE /lessons/:lesson_id/revisions/:id(.:format)      revisions#destroy
                     GET    /lessons(.:format)                               lessons#index
                     POST   /lessons(.:format)                               lessons#create
                     GET    /lessons/new(.:format)                           lessons#new
                     GET    /lessons/:id/edit(.:format)                      lessons#edit
                     GET    /lessons/:id(.:format)                           lessons#show
                     PUT    /lessons/:id(.:format)                           lessons#update
                     DELETE /lessons/:id(.:format)                           lessons#destroy
                root        /                                                home#index
                            /profile(.:format)                               profiles#show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Your question : 1) Saving the lessons to a user, and revisions to a user and lesson. At one point I had revisions saved to users, but lessons were not saving.`

see on your `lessons_form`

`<%= form_for @lesson, :url => new_lesson_revision_path(@lesson_id, @revision) do |f| %>`

You are using `new_lesson_revision_path` action form, this is not saving a `@lesson`, change your `lessons_form` to :

`<%= form_for @lesson do |f| %>`

and  `lessons_controller.rb` looks like :

```
  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @lesson = Lesson.new(params[:lesson]) 
    ....
    @lesson.save
    # see, redirect_to new lesson with params[lesson_id]
    redirect_to new_lesson_revision_path(params[:lesson_id])
 end
```

and on `revisions_controller.rb` looks like :

```
  def new
    @revision = Revision.new
    # get @lesson with params(:lesson_id)
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
  end
  def create
   @revision = @revision.new(params[:revision])
   @revision.user_id = current_user.id
   @revision.time_updated = DateTime.now
     respond_to do |format|
       if @revision.save
         format.html { redirect_to current_user.profile }
         format.json { }
       else
        render :new
        end
      end
  end
```

and on your `revisions_form`, you can add `lesson_id` with `hidden_field`

```
<%= form_for(@revision) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :lesson_id, :value => @lesson.id %>
  ..
  ..
<% end %>
```

`no 2`

Why should you not use nested form or multistep form?

- If you are use nested form, you can make lessons_form and
  revisons_form in one form.

  see screencasts [part
  1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and
  [part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)
  for nested form
- If you are using multistep form, you can resolved you problem `no 2`

  see screencasts [Wizard Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked)

**Addtional**

`error: undefined method 'revisions' for nil:NilClass - from the line @revision = @lesson.revisions.new(params[:revision])`

Because `@revision` is stand-alone on your case, you could change this

`@revision = @lesson.revisions.new(params[:revision])`

to

`@revision = @revision.new(params[:revision])`

Comment: Thanks so much! Lessons are saving now (I wonder why the respond_to do |format| block never seems to work, I was hoping to use it to include mobile formats). I see the revision form, but after submitting I get an error: undefined method `revisions' for nil:NilClass - from the line @revision = @lesson.revisions.new(params[:revision]). If I resolve this issue I'll accept this solution and comment on the fix for that last problem.

Comment: there's one little error sorry, `@revision = @lesson.revisions.new(params[:revision])` change to `@revision = @revision.new(params[:revision])`

Comment: The line @revision = Revision.new(params[:revision]) works! Thanks again for your help and the railscasts.